# command to print out large files, sorted, with sizes in human readable format

Tags: linux, bash

I've written a simple shell script that finds large files, mostly to save myself some typing.  The work is being done with:

```
find $dir -type f -size +"$size"M -printf '%s %p\n' | sort -rn
```

I'd like to turn the byte output into a human readable format.  I found ways online on how to manually do this, e.g.,

```
find $dir -type f -size +"$size"M -printf '%s %p\n' | sort -rn |
   awk '{ hum[1024**4]="TB"; hum[1024**3]="GB"; hum[1024**2]="MB"; hum[1024]="KB"; hum[0]="B";
      for (x=1024**4; x>=1024; x/=1024){
         if ($1>=x) { printf "%7.2f %s\t%s\n",$1/x,hum[x],$2;break }
      }}'
```

But this seems messy.  I was wondering: **is there was a standard way to convert bytes into a human-readable form**?

Of course, any alternate methods of producing the below output, given a directory and min-size as input, are also welcome:

```
   1.25 GB      /foo/barf
 598.80 MB      /foo/bar/bazf
 500.58 MB      /bar/bazf
 421.70 MB      /bar/baz/bamf
 ...
```

Note: This must work on both 2.4 and 2.6, and the output should be sorted.

Comment: Why does it list directories when you have `-type f` ?

Comment: it doesn't.  i just typed examples without thinking too much about it ;)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
find ... | sort -rn | cut -d\  -f2 | xargs df -h
```

for instance :) or

```
find $dir -type -f size +$size -print0 | xargs -0 ls -1hsS
```

(with a little inspiration borrowed from [olibre](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8943331/938111)).

Comment: very nice, though i believe this breaks on files with spaces in their names.

Comment: sure, but could be easily mended by passing `-d \n` option to `xargs`

Comment: cut is truncating the path/filename, not xargs

Comment: @user112358132134, I've just added another option for fighting spaces. But I think for the large amount of files first version is better. I don't know how many you have.

Comment: `cut -f2- -d ' '` is what i'm* looking for

Comment: @user112358132134, changing `-f2` to `-f2-` also shouldn't be a big deal. There's a lot of ways to cut off everything up to the first space, anyway.

Answer (score 13):

Use `du -h` and `sort -h`

```
find /your/dir -type f -size +5M -exec du -h '{}' + | sort -hr
```

**Explanations:**

- `du -h file1 file2 ...` prints the **d**isk **u**sage in **h**uman readable format of the given files.
- `sort -hr` sorts **h**uman readable numbers in **r**everse order (larger numbers first).
- the option `+` of `find -exec` will reduce the number of invocations of command `du` and therefore will speed up the execution. Here `+` can be replaced by `';'`.

You can remove option `-r` of `sort` command if you want the larger files being printed at the end. You can even use the simpler following command, but your terminal window buffer may be filled!

```
find /your/dir -type f -exec du -h '{}' + | sort -h
```

Or if you want just the top ten larger files:

```
find /your/dir -type f -exec du -h '{}' + | sort -hr | head
```

**Note:** option `-h` of `sort` has been introduced in about 2009, therefore this option may not be available on old distro (as Red Hat 5). Moreover the option `+` of `find -exec` is not available either on older distro (as Red Hat 4).

---

On old distro, you can use `xargs` instead of option `+` of `find -exec`. The command `ls` may also be used to print sorted files. But to guarantee the *sorting by size*, `xargs` must invoke `ls` only once. `xargs` can invoke `ls` only once if your amount of files is acceptable: it depends on the text length passed to `ls` argument (sum of all filenames length).

```
find /your/dir -type f -size +5M -print0 | xargs -0 ls -1Ssh
```

(with a little inspiration borrowed from [MichaelKrelin-hacker](https://stackoverflow.com/users/95382)).

**Explanations:**

- `ls -1` displays one file per line
- `ls -S` sorts by file size
- `ls -s` prints the file size
- `ls -h` prints sizes in human readable format

---

The fastest command may be using the above `ls -1Ssh` with the `+` option of `find -exec` but as above the amount of files must be acceptable to invoke `ls` only once in order to guarantee the *sorting by size* (option `+` of `find -exec` works in much the same way as `xargs`).

```
find /your/dir -type f -size +5M -exec ls -1Ssh '{}' +
```

To reduce the amount of files found, you can increase the threshold size: replace `+5M` by `+100M` for instance.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  I'd like the output to be sorted by byte size, which is why I'm looking for a method to turn bytes into human-readable (since I couldn't via find).

Comment: Hi @user112358132134. I have added the option `-S` (`ls` command) => files are sorting by size :-)

Comment: wait.  this will only work with -exec+, and (sadly) this will need to work on older systems without that.

Comment: @user112358132134 As I said on the answer: use `';'` instead of `'+`' on old systems (if `sed` version is older than **4.1.5**)

Comment: right, what i meant when i said that it wouldn't work is that the **sorting** won't work.

Comment: Hi @user112358132134. OK I see you mean the `ls` command has to be called exactly once in order to guarantee the sort => I update my answer ;-)

Comment: What if this are really much files and one want to sort correctly anyway?

Comment: Hi @jan. Thank you for your feedback. I have completed my old 2012 answer. I hope the answer is more pedagogic. Please let me know if the answer fits your needs. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

To find files > 10Mb in current directory sorted by size with human readable form

`find . -type f -size +10M | xargs du -sh | sort -rn`